# Puppeteer web scraping is not loading profile for scraping

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to get the puppeteer web scraping to scrape clutch.co using the below scripts but not working properly. I'm developing a simple web scraper for clutch.co. I want to extract contacts and company names for my lead generation project. In fact, to achieve this goal would improve my understanding of javascript.

Brower.js

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function startBrowser() {
  let browser;
  try {
    console.log("Opening the browser......");
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      args: ["--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Could not create a browser instance => : ", err);
  }
  return browser;
}

module.exports = {
  startBrowser,
};
```

Pagecontroller.js

```
const pageScraper = require("./pageScraper");
async function scrapeAll(browserInstance) {
  let browser;
  try {
    browser = await browserInstance;
    await pageScraper.scraper(browser);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Could not resolve the browser instance => ", err);
  }
}

module.exports = (browserInstance) => scrapeAll(browserInstance);
```

Pagescraper.js

```
const scraperObject = {
  url: "https://clutch.co/sitemap",
  async scraper(browser) {
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    console.log(`Navigating to ${this.url}...`);
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
    await page.goto(this.url);

    // Wait for the required DOM to be rendered
    await page.waitForSelector(".container");

    // Get the link to all Categories
    let urls = await page.$$eval(".sitemap-menu > li", (links) => {
      // Extract the links from the data
      links = links.map((el) => el.querySelector("div > a").href);
      return links;
    });

    // Loop through each of those links, open a new page instance and get the relevant data from them
    let pagePromise = (link) =>
      new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let dataObj = {};
        let newPage = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
        await newPage.goto(link);
        dataObj["companyName"] = await newPage.$eval(
          "h3 > a",
          (text) => text.textContent
        );
        dataObj["tagLine"] = await newPage.$eval(
          ".tagline",
          (text) => text.textContent
        );
        resolve(dataObj);
        await newPage.close();
      });

    for (link in urls) {
      let currentPageData = await pagePromise(urls[link]);
      // scrapedData.push(currentPageData);
      console.log(currentPageData);
    }
  },
};

module.exports = scraperObject;
```

index.js

```
const browserObject = require("./browser");
const scraperController = require("./pageController");

//Start the browser and create a browser instance
let browserInstance = browserObject.startBrowser();

// Pass the browser instance to the scraper controller
scraperController(browserInstance);
```

I can't get the script to load and scrape the profile pages. it keeps giving me errors.

Comment: Try to replace `for (link in urls)` with `for (link of urls)`.